# How to show third bracket [ ] inside html paragraph tag?

Tags: html, entity

If I want to show `[<][>]` symbols within a paragraph in html page, entity name is required.

So in a web search I found `&#60` for `<` and `&#62` for `>` but the problem is I searched a lot and still found no entity name for `[` and `]`.

Can anyone help me how to show `[ ]` inside a paragraph?

Comment: nothing.. you just use them as it is

Comment: If you tried even to write it you would find by yourself that you can just type them as they are... unless you are using some framework that uses [ and ] as special symbols...

Comment: You should use `&#60;` and `&#62;`, since the trailing semicolon is part of the reference. On the other hand, the “>” can always be written as such; it is just some people’s habit to use a character reference for it, too, for symmetry. Also note that you can use the reference `&lt;` instead of `&#60;`. It’s easier to remember (`lt` for “less than”).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type `[` or `]`.

- They have no special meaning in HTML
- They appear in the ASCII character set
- They appear on standard keyboards

There is no need to use an entity for them.

[HTML 5 defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references) `&lbrack;` and `&rbrack;` if you really want to use 7 times as many bytes as you need though.

Comment: In the very unlikely case where typing “[” or “]” is impossible, they can be written using numeric character references `&#91;` and `&#93;`, using a general notation based on the Unicode number of a character.

Comment: This actually can be handy in Wordpress if you want to display a shortcode in the content area without actually calling the shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

Right and left square bracket [ ] don't have `HTML entity name` by default, but they are included in `HTML5` as `&lbrack;` & `&rbrack;` (as @Quentin point out)

If it's require, you can use the `entity decimal` equivalent, or unicode if you'r using javascript to include them. (cross-browser) or the entity name asigned in `HTML5` if you are goint to work only in modern browsers.

Example: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5b/browsertest.htm

```
              decimal   visual    named      Unicode
HTML Entity |  &#91;  |    [   | &lbrack; |  U+005B
HTML Entity |  &#93;  |    ]   | &rbrack; |  U+005D
HTML Entity |  &#60;  |    <   |  &lt;    |  U+003C
HTML Entity |  &#62;  |    >   |  &gt;    |  U+003E
```

further reading and good reference for this... http://www.fileformat.info/

Comment: Entity references have `&`, not `$`, as the leading character.

Comment: mistyped `&` character.. thanks for the advice (that deserves a negative vote?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display [<][>] in your p tag you can do it as follows

```
<p>[&lt;][&gt;]</p>
```

Comment: The question is asking about `[` and `]`, not `<` and `>`.

Comment: [  &#60; ][ &#62;]  this is the answer. :)